Video playback issue in Safari despite correct autoplay configuration (controls, playsInline, muted, loop, autoplay)
I'm encountering a perplexing issue with a decorative video integration on a website, specifically related to Safari browser (Version 17.4.1). The setup involves embedding adaptive videos, catering to both landscape and portrait orientations, with automatic playback. While the video autoplays correctly upon initially loading the page, subsequent page refreshes result in the video failing to play, displaying only the fallback poster ./img/img_1.png.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">
</head>
<body>

<video controls playsInline preload='none' muted loop autoplay class="mm-banner-video"
       poster="./img/img_1.png">
  <source width="1920" height="1080"
          src="./videos/desktop.mp4"
          type="video/mp4" media="(orientation: landscape)">

  <source width="1080" height="1080"
          src="./videos/mobile.mp4"
          type="video/mp4" media="(orientation: portrait)">
</video>

</body>
</html>


Adding the controls attribute resolves the playback persistence issue, but I don't want these controls as the videos are purely decorative.
Strangely, removing the link to my stylesheet also resolves the problem, even without the controls attribute.. Notably, my stylesheet contains no rules.
Adding directly to the src attribute in the video tag effectively resolves the issue. It loads and plays even when forcing a page reload. However, this solution doesn't allow me to have a different video depending on the screen orientation (landscape vs portrait).

Thank you in advance .
